# How to exclude query in specific table register

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to nest some data in a query. I'm listing users, then showing a button to edit permissions, it would send the user_id and do the query to which permissions he has. There are two tables:

permission

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS permission(
      id uuid PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
      name varchar(200) NOT NULL,
      platform varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    );
```

users_permission

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users_permission(
      id uuid PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
      users_id uuid NOT NULL REFERENCES users(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
      permission_id uuid NOT NULL REFERENCES permission(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
      create_active boolean NOT NULL,
      read_active boolean NOT NULL,
      update_active boolean NOT NULL,
      delete_active boolean NOT NULL,
      is_active boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT true
    );
```

The users_permission receives a uuid from the users table.
With that in mind, how could I do a query which would:
-Get all the results from users_permission;
-Get all the results from permission, but excluding the ones which are already used in users_permission (the one that is related to users_id).

I could exclude it generally, if it is related to the users_permission table in any register, but I want to show user specific permissions.

Summarizing, how should I use SQL to get the list of permissions, with the linked (users_permission) and the unlinked (permission) permissions, for a specific user?

Comment: Sample data would really help.  Why do you have a permissions table and then pivot individual permissions in the user/permission table?

Comment: This is our user access management style (i'm kinda testing it), for example, we have Manage Users in the permission table. In the users_permission I define if one user can read, update, delete, etc in the table.
The permission table is like a general action, you think that this is a bad design?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I was thinking if this model should be changed (i'm starting it yet, so it's easier to fix). Something more specific, because in this case the permissions are separated by one main group e.g Manage Users, and then it's subdivided in 4 parts:
Create: Create User;
Update: Update Data/Update Password;
Read: Read User List;
Delete: Delete User;
Every permission would be grouped like this, so in the read part by example I could have two API routes .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query below solved my problem

```
SELECT
    UP.users_id,
    P.id as permission_id, 
    P.name as permission_name
    FROM users_permission UP
LEFT JOIN permission P
    on P.id = UP.permission_id
where UP.users_id = someUserId
UNION
SELECT
    null,
    P.id as permission_id, 
    P.name as permission_name
FROM   permission P
where  NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT *
   FROM   users_permission
   WHERE  users_permission.permission_id = P.id
  AND users_permission.users_id = someUserId)
```